# DateTime.ParseExact - why yy turns into 2015 not 1915

Tags: c#, parsing, datetime

Why does .NET assume that from following we mean year as 2015, not 1915.

```
var d = DateTime.ParseExact("20/11/15", "dd/MM/yy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

I guess, it tries proximity, but is there a reasonable design decision behind it?

Comment: why it should assume 1915 and not 2015? ;)

Comment: The ["yy" Custom Format Specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#yySpecifier) uses the [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax` Property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax(v=vs.110).aspx). "The initial value of this property is derived from the settings in the regional and language options portion of Control Panel."

Comment: Why would it assume 1915 and not 1815?

Comment: @Martijn : That would be silly! There was no C# compiler for the Jacquard looms in 1815...

Comment: @BrianDrummond, there was none in 1915 either :-)

Comment: yay... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2000_problem

Answer (score 16, accepted):

It uses [`Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendar.twodigityearmax(v=vs.110).aspx) property.

> This property allows a 2-digit year to be properly translated to a 4-digit year. For example, if this property is set to 2029, the 100-year range is from 1930 to 2029. Therefore, a 2-digit value of 30 is interpreted as 1930, while a 2-digit value of 29 is interpreted as 2029.

For en-GB the value of this property is 2029. It can be changed in Control Panel:

> The initial value of this property is derived from the settings in the regional and language options portion of Control Panel.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4(v=vs.110).aspx#yySpecifier):

> In a parsing operation, a two-digit year that is parsed using the "yy" custom format specifier is interpreted based on the Calendar.TwoDigitYearMax property of the format provider's current calendar.

Comment: If it were 2029 for en-GB, then he'd be getting 2015 back from his ParseExact operation.

Comment: @Powerlord the OP is getting 2015, but he actually wants 1915.

Comment: @user1666620 Was curious to know what's was the basis of CLRs decision to say 2015.

Comment: @Yahya: The CLR only retrieves the setting from the system. You can change it.

Answer (score 27):

This is a system setting you can customize for your locale if you want:

[image]

Comment: That mouse pointer ! for a moment i thought my computer freezed!

Comment: There's a confusing mixture of languages!

Comment: I still use a German locale (albeit with ISO 8601 date format), but English as UI language. I'm used to it ;-)

Comment: Everyone should use ISO 8601. Anything else is chaos.

Comment: Psft... I'm an American... our way is always right :P

Comment: @MatthewWhited: Well, ISO 8601 is *your* national standard ;-) (It was merely adopted in DIN 5008 to make it mandatory in German, too)